# What is this number in for-each of Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

On https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._for-each%29%29 what is the number 23 for?

```
(for-each (lambda (arg)
              (printf "Got ~a\n" arg)
              23)
            '(1 2 3 4))
```

The  code works even without '23'.

Comment: It's to illustrate what is written on the line above the example code... the result of the procedure, in this case 23, is ignored.

Comment: I think you should put this as an answer since this is not clear on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to illustrate what is written on the line above the example code... the result of the procedure, in this case 23, is ignored.

Since it is ignored, you could put any other value(s), or even nothing as you did.

Comment: How is it different from simple 'for': (for ((item '(1 2 3 4))) (printf "Got ~a\n" item)) ? What is so special about for-each that differentiates it from a simple 'for' loop?

Comment: `for-each` is standard Scheme, the `for` procedures are specific to Racket. In this case they amount to the same thing. The documentation compares `for-each` to `map`; they are similar, but `map` used the result of the procedure whereas `for-each` doesn't.

Comment: `for-each` can be mapped to `for` and `map` can be mapped for `for/list` @mso `for` loops doesn't really exist in Scheme. They are just sugar for recursive procedures.

Answer (score 1):

`for-each` is a special version of `map` that totally ignores the return value of each applications and does not make a resulting list. If the procedure that is supplied does not have side effects the whole expression would become dead code.

`for` is a special form that lets you write `for-each` with different syntax. It's `map` equivalent is called `for/list`. `for` is unqiue to `#!racket` while `for-each` exists in all Scheme language and dialects. `for` and friends, being a macro, does have more features than the procedure versions, like the possibility to have more accumulators and stop conditions.